# Why does NumPy disallows string seed but the Random library allows it in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random

When using the `random` library in Python, I can do the following just fine

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed("twenty five")
```

but if i'm using NumPy to generate random numbers, I cannot set the seed with a string

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed("twenty five")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_mt19937.pyx", line 178, in numpy.random._mt19937.MT19937._legacy_seeding
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 244, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.seed
  File "_mt19937.pyx", line 166, in numpy.random._mt19937.MT19937._legacy_seeding
  File "_mt19937.pyx", line 186, in numpy.random._mt19937.MT19937._legacy_seeding
TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<U11') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Is it possible for NumPy to accept string as seed ?

And if not, is there a **correct** way to transform the string into an int for setting the seed in NumPy ?

What is the mechanism behind the `seed` function of the `random` library that makes it able to accept string seeds ?

Comment: Why would you care?  You have no guarantee that `numpy.random` and Python's `random` use the same algorithm.

Comment: Because I'm curious and I'd like to use NumPy AND a string for the seed

Comment: It is pointless.  If you're using a base seed, any integer is just as good as any other.  And remember, you have the source -- you can go look up what `random.seed` does.

Comment: @TimRoberts I still find it interesting to know what way the `random` library finds best to convert a string into an integer to keep the input space relatively similar. Also I don't think I should justify every question I post on stack overflow with the reason why I care, but I might be wrong

Comment: I'm not out of line to point out when someone is focusing on the wrong things.  The exact value of a random number seed has no meaning at all.  No seed is better or "more random" than another.  `seed(1)` produces a completely different (and valid) sequence from `seed(2)`.  Thus, there is no "best" algorithm for translating a string.  Using the ASCII value of the first character would be every bit as good.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is true when setting the seed only once. However if during the rng the seed is set a second time, I'd rather have a correct way of "mixing" the text of the seed in a deterministic (like the random.seed with version=2 does) instead of implementing my own mixing of the text that might result in 2 close (hamming distance) strings colliding to one int (if for exemple I took the sum of the ord() of each character in the string)

Comment: Hence, the reason why you should use an unambiguous integer.

Comment: So the question is why does python translate a string to a valid integer seed, while numpy developers didn't see a need to to do that?  That's a theologjcal queston.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

From the python docs,

```
random.seed(a=None, version=2)
```

> With version 2 (the default), a str, bytes, or bytearray object gets converted to an int and all of its bits are used.

This means `"twenty five"` is not converted into `25` but rather by its ascii representation (and its SHA512 digest as Tim Roberts points out in the comments).

Note, this feature is now deprecated.

Edit:

The source code

```
    elif version == 2 and isinstance(a, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        if isinstance(a, str):
            a = a.encode()
        a = int.from_bytes(a + _sha512(a).digest(), 'big')
```

Comment: That's almost true.  Remember, we have the source code.  The ASCII values of the characters PLUS the SHA512 digest of the string are used as a large integer to seed the sequence.

Comment: So it looks at the bit representation of the string twenty five and use that as an integer for the seed ? So `twenty five` would be converted to '1110100 1110111 1100101 1101110 1110100 1111001 100000 1100110 1101001 1110110 1100101' so 69026774765723335687013 in base 10 ? What happens if the number is too big? (as I guess there is a limit to the size of the seed)

Comment: It is the bit representation of `twenty-five`, after the SHA512 digest of the string "twenty-five" is appended.

Comment: +Nathan Marotte I'll edit in the relevant source code

Comment: The underlying C code upon which `random` is based returns a double-precision float, so anything more than 53 bits of seed is pointless.

Comment: @TimRoberts that's only "pointless" if you're using the RNG to generate exactly one double.  the more you're generating the more entropy you want the seed to have.  getting unbiased bits tends to be difficult, hence taking the hash of a larger space.  256bits of entropy is often considered a good tradeoff, but will depend on the PRNG in use

Comment: Entropy is critical if you're starting a RANDOM sequence.  But if you're using a fixed seed for a repeatable sequence, as he is, then entropy is irrelevant.  Any integer will do.